# CButton sends WM_PARENTNOTIFY message to ancestors but CMFCButton does not. Why?

Tags: windows, mfc, message-handlers, cbutton

I am working on a Windows application (built with VS 2019) that relies heavily on MFC functionality. I have a class that is derived from the `CWnd` class that contains `CMFCButton` objects (children) which are defined dynamically within the `OnCreate` handler for the class. I would like for the `CMFCButton` objects to send the `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` message to its ancestors, so that they can do some additional handling of the mouse events, but they don't. I tried changing the button type to `CButton` class and noticed that `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` was sent as expected. The `CMFCButton` and `CButton` were defined/created using all the same parameters. Using `CButton` seems to solve the issue but I also make use of the extended `CMFCButton` functionality to control the buttons' appearances.

Can anyone please explain the change in behaviour of these two button types and how I can get `CMFCButtons` to also send the `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` message?

Comment: Does your `CMFCButton` have the `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` [extended window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) set?

Comment: No, it's defined using the Create method rather than CreateEx. I've only specified the following styles: WS_CHILD|WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE. My understanding is that the WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY is only a default style if the button is created as part of Dialog template.

Comment: I've been using `CMFCButton` extensively and never seen such behavior. BTW, I prefer to create them as a normal button in the resources and then `DDX` them into a `CMFCButton` variable in the dialog code, because otherwise it gets human unreadable hexadecimal strings in the .rc file, and they will be a pain in ass for translations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This behaviour does seem unexpected. Do you think defining the `CMFCButton` as a resource instead of in the code could have an effect on it's behaviour?